# How to use Hidden Wire and In Front for a low poly retopology?

Tags: retopology

If I am retopologising on top of a high poly mesh, It gets really confusing when the vertices from behind the object show through the foreground mesh I am working on.

Sometimes and I don't know what the difference is - Blender culls the vertices behind the faces I have made.

This is really helpful and cuts down on clutter.

Sometimes, it shows the vertices through the mesh and the settings are the same - Does anyone know what causes it to behave differently and how I can force it to cull the vertices behind the faces I am working with?

**Edit**, I seem to have accidentally found the solution to this problem. I decided to switch to shade smooth at one point and noticed that the normals were misbehaving. So I **reset vectors** then this resulted in flipped normals, so I **recalculate outside** Once this was done - the hidden wire in front properties were behaving properly (obscuring the background vertices). So I assume this issue was due to normals being weird.

Comment: please improve your question with screenshots so we know what you are talking about. Also show us some settings you made like "rendered view" or "x-ray"...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `in front` option to enable a x-ray effect for the object that you wish to stay in front.

**Note:** This option only works in `solid` mode unfortunately.

[image]